# Can a class return a static instance of itself? (in c#)

Tags: c#

Right now my class is set up as:

`enum Unit{Inches,Centimeters};`

Later on I have a step that sets all of the properties of each of these units into my classes instance variables.  For example:

```
int unitBase; //10 for metric, 16 for american
int label;
switch(unit)
{
    case Unit.Inches: unitBase = 16; unitLabel = "\"";break;
    case Unit.Centimeters: unitBase = 10; unitLabel = "cm";break;
}
```

I would rather store this all in a Unit class or struct.  Then, I would like to be able to access it in the same way you access colors, for example.  You say `Color.Blue` for a blue color, I would like to say `Unit.Inches` for inches... That is why I dont make a unit base class and simply extend it.

I know that there is a way to do this!  Could anyone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: static and instance dont go together, i think what youre trying to do makes sense, but youve described it wrong

Comment: How could I describe it?  I don't know what I am trying to do is called...

Comment: Are you describing a singleton? Or are you describing a static class with static methods for each unit type?

Comment: class with static methods for each unit type.  I think BrokenGlass's answer below might be what I want.

Comment: Don't forget to click the checkmark next to the answer you use. This is an important part of asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use static properties:

```
public enum UnitSpecifier{Inches,Centimeters};

public class Unit
{
    int unitBase; //10 for metric, 16 for american
    string unitLabel;

    public Unit(UnitSpecifier unit)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case UnitSpecifier.Inches: unitBase = 16; unitLabel = @"\"; break;
            case UnitSpecifier.Centimeters: unitBase = 10; unitLabel = "cm"; break;
        }
    }

    public static readonly Unit Inches = new Unit(UnitSpecifier.Inches);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public struct Unit {
    public static readonly Unit Inches = new Unit(16, "\"");
    public static readonly Unit Centimeters = new Unit(10, "cm");

    private readonly int _unitBase;
    private readonly string _unitLabel;

    static Unit() { }

    private Unit(int unitBase, string unitLabel) {
        this._unitBase = unitBase;
        this._unitLabel = unitLabel;
    }

    public int UnitBase {
        get { return this._unitBase; }
    }

    public string UnitLabel {
        get { return this._unitLabel; }
    }
}
```